# Vaadin 8 Grid theme option

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

this addThemeVariants is not coming in vaadin 8. I want my grid with no border and grayish background color. This option is coming in 6. https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples.

```
grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_NO_BORDER,
        GridVariant.LUMO_NO_ROW_BORDERS, GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);
```

Tried Valotheme, but no luck

[image]

I want my vaadin grid to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 8 there is no predefined style names for Grid. However the styles of the Grid are based on few SASS variables, which you can easily redefine in your theme scss file.

```
$v-grid-border: none;
$v-border-size: "";
```